# SSIS WebService Task Insert into XML Header

Tags: sql-server, xml, web-services, ssis

I have an issue where I have an XML web service where the input parameters are in the header, as opposed to the body of the XML.  This is causing the parameters section of the Web Service Task to be blank.

The SSIS Web Service task does not appear to handle input parameters in the header.

When I use soapUI it shows the inputs in the header (see attached picture)

I’m guessing I’m going to have to write a script task to do this but if anyone has come across this before and can point me in the right direction then that would be great.

Is it possible to butcher the WSDL to do this? (I rather wouldn’t though)
Many thanks in advance and if any more information is required then please do not hesitate to ask.

[image: SoapUIXML]

Answer (score 2):

To answer my own question....

This turned out to be a frustrating one.  The short answer to my question is yes, you have to use code to update header parameters .

I had to write some c# to consume the webservice and spit out the data.   I also created a proxy class using wsdl.exe following https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155134.aspx.

Initially, I was writing this as a script component source but kept getting the following error:

Error at Data Flow Task [XML Source [1]]: The value for custom property "XMLData" on XML Source is incorrect.
Error at Data Flow Task [SSIS.Pipeline]: "XML Source" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN".
Error at Data Flow Task [SSIS.Pipeline]: "XML Source.Outputs[XML Source Output]" contains no output columns. An asynchronous output must contain output columns.
Error at Data Flow Task [SSIS.Pipeline]: One or more component failed validation.
Error at Data Flow Task: There were errors during task validation.
 (Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration)

I debugged this in visual studio, outputting to a console screen.  All worked fine.

Following this I recreated this as a script task and outputted to a variable.  All worked fine.

I’d like to thank the following links and blogs for help:

http://blog.reckonedforce.com/tag/consuming-web-services-in-ssis-script-task/

Hope this helps someone.